# Why port forwarding does not work in QEMU?

Tags: debian, windows, virtual-machine, qemu, port-forwarding

How to redirect port 5555 of Host OS to port 80 of Guest OS?

Host OS: Debian Jessie 64-bit

Guest OS: Windows XP SP3 32-bit

I'm using the following commands:

```
qemu-system-i386 -enable-kvm \
  -name 'WinXP' \
  -cpu host \
  -vga qxl \
  -m 2048 \
  -soundhw ac97 \
  -drive file=/home/ccsadegh/VMs/winxp.img,if=virtio \
  -net nic,model=virtio \
  -net user,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:5555-:80 \
  -spice port=3001,disable-ticketing \
  -device virtio-serial-pci \
  -device virtserialport,chardev=spicechannel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
  -chardev spicevmc,id=spicechannel0,name=vdagent &
```

and

```
SPICE_NOGRAB=1 spicec -h localhost -p 3001
```

But after installing IIS in Guest OS, if i visit `127.0.0.1:5555` or `localhost:5555` URL via Iceweasel in Host OS, it does not redirect to the home page of IIS (Iceweasel Error: The connection was reset).

`iptables` and other stuff are not changed. Network configuration of  Guest OS is not changed. My host OS network is configured via GNOME desktop settings to have static IP address.

What did i wrong or forget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by changing Windows Firewall settings in Guest OS (Windows), and adding an exception for port 80 to the list.